# Debugging Shell Arguments

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a command like `echo` that shows the arguments as they were received?

For example `echo "a b" c` shows `a b c`

but I would like to see something like `"a b" "c"`.

Comment: `set -x` 6 more to go

Comment: @jesse_b thanks but that only works for scripts, not when checking why a single command does not work (e.g. a shell command in ranger).

Comment: Why doesn't it work for a single command?

Comment: E.g. `map tu shell -w diskutil unmount %f` - I can just prepend `echo` to see what parameters are given in %f ... how would I add `set -x`?

Comment: `set -x; map tu shell -w diskutil unmount %f`

Comment: that's a ranger config but `map tu shell -w set -x; diskutil unmount %f` actually does work. that's helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `printf`, e.g.:

```
$ printf ">%s<\n" "a b" c
>a b<
>c<
```

Or use whichever separators you like, but note that it doesn't produce shell-style quoted output like `set -x` does. And it always prints the format string at least once, so `printf ">%s<\n"` without other arguments produces `><`.

Or to get shell-style quoted output in Bash:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "a b" c
a\ b
c
```

The downside of `%q` is that it prefers backslashes instead of quotes, so the output is ugly and harder to read than necessary.

Of course, you could also create an external script to do that, but it might too heavy a solution for your situation:

```
$ cat args.sh
#/bin/bash
printf "%d args: " "$#"
for x do
    printf "%s " "${x@Q}"   # nicer output than printf %q
done
echo

$ ./args.sh "a b" c
2 args: 'a b' 'c'
```